# Insert space in front of the urls in the string

Tags: javascript

I have string having urls. So when the user type it i have to add space in front of the url.

This is the string:

`Hello this my profilehttps://my_pforile and thishttps://my_profile2`

I need the string like below:

`Hello this my profile https://my_pforile and this https://my_profile2`

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: use string maipulation

Comment: Can you add your code, please?

Comment: Do you have any code ? so i can look into that

Comment: There is no jQuery specific in manipulating a string

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to replace `https://` with a white-space prefix.

```js
let str = 'Hello this my profilehttps://my_pforile and thishttps://my_profile2';

console.log(
  str.replace(/https:\/\//g, ' $&')
)

// or with positive look-ahead
console.log(
  str.replace(/(?=https:\/\/)/g, ' ')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can work also,You can string split with join

```js
let str="Hello this my profilehttps://my_pforile and thishttps://my_profile2"

let newstring=str.split("profile").join("profile ");
console.log(newstring)
```